# Words ending in -ht, words ending in -th

Tags: affixes

Look at the endings of the following words:

blig**ht**, boug**ht**, bread*th*, broug**ht**, caug**ht**, delig**ht**, dep*th*, fif*th*, foug**ht**, four*th*, frig**ht**, freig**ht**, heig**ht**, lig**ht**, plig**ht**, taug**ht**, thoug**ht**, wid*th*, ...

As you may have already noticed, some of the words in that list end in **ht**, whereas the rest of them end in *th*. I have some questions regarding those endings:

**I**. Do all words of the English language that end with **ht** end, actually, with **ght**?

**II**. Is there any rule of thumb out there that helps one to recall (or determine) when the ending of a given word is *th* and not **ht** (or the other way around)?

Thanks in advance for your insig**ht**ful replies!

Comment: Well 'yacht' is an exception. However most do and all such words end either in 'ght' or 'cht' apart from words that are directly borrowed from other languages.

Comment: I. the only exceptions listed by [Wordfind.com](http://www.wordfind.com/ends-with/ht/) are *borscht/borsht, klepht, waucht, whisht, pht, phpht, yacht, licht, wecht, baht, echt.* Of these, only *yacht* seems at all common to me. II. After any letters besides *gh*, we use "th". They're pronounced differently.

Comment: As for a rule, well you have formulated it yourself.  The exceptions don't end in  'ght' or 'cht'.

Comment: @sumelic, Ah yes, whisht. More Scottish or Irish than English.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly you're running into trouble remembering which words end with "th" and which end with "ht." Do these endings have identical pronunciation in your dialect? Or do you only write the language, and never speak or hear it? The usefulness of our answers may depend on this detail.

Comment: @user867: So, the rule of dumb that you are putting forward goes basically thus: "LISTEN CAREFULLY AND PRONOUNCE PROPERLY"? I wonder in what universe such a general suggestion would count as a rule of thumb for the very specific need which prompted my second question...

Comment: @J.H.S. I wasn't putting forth a rule of thumb. I was seriously asking. If the OP was, for example, deaf, they'd need a rule that didn't depend on being able to sound things out. On the other hand, if they're learning English as a second language, we might be able to come up with something that makes sense in terms of their own native language. Knowing why they have difficulty makes it easier to write an answer that they'll find useful.

Answer (score 2):

All the words in your list which end with *-th* have it as a suffix, meaning either an ordinal:

> four -> fourth
>
> five -> fifth

or an abstract quantity which is a measure

> broad -> breadth
>
> deep -> depth
>
> wide -> width

The remaining words, ending in *-t*, either have the past-tense suffix *-t* (which is a variant of *-ed*, but is never *-th*):

> buy -> bought
>
> teach -> taught

or have no discernable suffix at all, as in *delight* and *fright*.

The sole exceptions are *height* and *weight*, which are in the same class as *width* etc, and one might expect to be *heigth* or *weighth*, but they aren't. These two need to be learnt as exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

In my `speculum.txt` file (`rev wordlist.txt | sort | rev > speculum.txt`),
`g/.*ght$/` finds 8 words reverse-alphabetized **after** `.*ght$`:

> *klepht Yasht wheesht tweesht accomplisht wisht borsht fusht.*

And 35 words reverse-alphabetized **before** `.*ght$`:

> *Aht
>   baht
>   Mooachaht
>   Ehatisaht
>   Ahousaht
>   Poblacht
>   Eoghanacht
>   Pacht
>   mynpacht
>   Gaeltacht
>   yacht
>   aeroyacht
>   superyacht
>   Diancecht
>   landsknecht
>   pecht
>   Albrecht
>   Utrecht
>   wecht
>   slicht
>   micht
>   richt
>   unricht
>   wricht
>   wicht
>   ocht
>   thocht
>   wrocht
>   socht
>   borscht
>   straucht
>   waucht
>   feucht
>   throucht
>   mowcht.*